# Python exchangelib: check if item is a message or not

Tags: python, exchangelib

I got an error when retrieve items using exchangelib. Is there any method to detect whether the item is an email, and if not, just ignore it? The following code raises `AttributeError: 'MeetingRequest' object has no attribute 'flag')` since meeting requests don't have a `flag` field. Or is there any method to view the type of the item?

```
import re
import sys
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, ServiceAccount, \
    EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone, Configuration, NTLM, CalendarItem, Message, \
    Mailbox, Attendee, Q, ExtendedProperty, FileAttachment, ItemAttachment, \
    HTMLBody, Build, Version

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

tz = EWSTimeZone.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')

creds = Credentials(
    username='domain\userID', 
    password='password')
)
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='myemail@domain',
    credentials=creds, 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE)

class Flag(ExtendedProperty):
    property_tag = 0x1090
    property_type = 'Integer'

Message.register('flag', Flag)  


if(len(sys.argv) == 1):
    yesterday = tz.localize(EWSDateTime.now() - timedelta(days=3))
    today = tz.localize(EWSDateTime.now())
    fYear= yesterday.year
    fMonth= yesterday.month
    fDay= yesterday.day
    tYear = today.year
    tMonth = today.month
    tDay = today.day
elif(len(sys.argv) == 3):
    fromDate = sys.argv[1]
    toDate = sys.argv[2]
    fYear = fromDate[:4]
    fMonth = fromDate[4:6]
    fDay = fromDate[-2:]
    tYear = toDate[:4]
    tMonth = toDate[4:6]
    tDay = toDate[-2:]

for item in account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__range=(
    #tz.localize(EWSDateTime.now() - timedelta(days=1)),
    #tz.localize(EWSDateTime.now())
    tz.localize(EWSDateTime(int(fYear), int(fMonth), int(fDay))),
    tz.localize(EWSDateTime(int(tYear), int(tMonth), int(tDay)))
    )):
    subA=item.subject
    snd=item.sender.email_address
    fg=str(item.flag)
str(item.datetime_received.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')).strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
        rT = str(item.datetime_received.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        cat=str(item.categories)
        if not subA:
            subA=""
            a="\"Inbox\",\""+snd+"\",\""+subA+"\",\""+rT+"\",\""+cat+"\",\""+fg+"\""
            print(a)
        else:
            subA = re.sub('\"\,\"', '\\"\,\\"', subA.rstrip())
            a="\"Inbox\",\""+snd+"\",\""+subA+"\",\""+rT+"\",\""+cat+"\",\""+fg+"\""
            decoded = a.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the class of the returned item: `if type(item) == Message` and ignore the ones that don't match.

If you want to avoid the cause of the error, you need to also register the `flag` property on the `MeetingRequest` class (and `MeetingResponse` and `MeetingCancellation` if you have those in your folder).

Comment: thanks reply and i tried to add below, 
`if isinstance(item, Message):
  print ("This is message")
  print (item)
`
but still return >>> `This is a message
MeetingRequest(mime_content=b'Received: from HKG`  the meeting request still identify as Message

Comment: Sorry about that. MeetingRequest is actually a subclass of Message, so `isinstance()` will match both. Use `type()` instead. I updated the answer.